# django template rows of multiple items

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm creating a catalogue, where there is a list of items of undefined length. I want to spit it out in rows with three columns each. So I have the following html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">item 1
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">item 2
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">item 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">item 4
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">item 5
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">item 6
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm stuck as to how I can implement this as a django template? How can I split it up so that a new row starts after three items?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="row">
{% for item in items %}
    <div class="three columns">{{ item }}
    </div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
</div>
<div class="row">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Ouch, I'm too late with the same answer

Comment: Fantastic - that's perfect. I didn't know about the divisibleby option - I'll look more into the documentation.

Comment: Won't this break if you happen to have a row with less than three items? The `divisibleby:3` won't be met for that row, and you'll be missing a closing `</div>`. I think the solution that creates sublists is more stable.

Comment: You saved my day :*

Answer (score 5):

You could try  to create a custom template filter, that would return a **list of list of 3-items**.

Quick attempt :

```
@register.filter
def splitByThree(data):
    return [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
```

And then in your template :

```
{% load splitByThree %}

{% for list in data|splitByThree %}
<div class="row">
{% for item in list %}
<div class="three columns">{{ item }}</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: There is a set of more flexible ways to split list into list of lists here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Answer (score 4):

You can use `forloop.counter` variable and `divisibleby` filter. The code will be close to this:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="three columns">{{ item }}</div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
        </div>
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
         </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry don't have enough reputation to just comment **jpic**'s answer(the accepted one), for **Jinja2**, use:

```
<div class="row">
{% for item in items %}
    <div class="three columns">{{ item }}
    </div>
    {% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) %}
</div>
<div class="row">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

details are [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#tests).