# Django template row alternate for multiple content

Tags: django

I've a template design like this

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
</div>
```

and I've tried using this article [django template rows of multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048086/django-template-rows-of-multiple-items)

But output doesnt come as required. How can I do as required.

What I've tried:

```
{% for item in items %}
<div class="row">
   {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
       <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
       {% else %}
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
   {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello, could you share you complete code? As you can see on the other post, this is a loop you need to create.

Comment: This is your problem. The opening "div tag" is inside the loop. Let me show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produce one row per item. If I'm correct, you want 2 items per row.

```
{% with items_length = items|length%}
<div class="row">
{% for item in items %}
<div class="col-sm-{% cycle '4' '8'%}"></div>
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 and forloop.counter < items_length %}
</div>
<div class="row">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endwith %}
```

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 0):

The following is one way to do it:

```
{% for item in items %}
<div class="row">
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Notice the use of `forloop.counter0`.

Comment: Shows individual data twice

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't, except you're running another for loop in the one you've shown

Comment: @nikolas Show us the exact code which u r putting in the template. Something is wrong there.